# Force AMAZON S3 Bucket to download https

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Newbie question here so be gentle :)
Our membership site has a valid SSL certificate.
When I hover over a PDF file in our AWS S3 Bucket - the file also shows as HTTPS....
But when members download a PDF file from that bucket, Google Chrome Developer Tools shows the file is being redirected through a HTTP bucket of the exact same name as the HTTPS one that I hovered over 2 seconds ago....? So we & members are getting the "File can't be downloaded securely" error on Chrome.
The file IS Sourced via the S3 Flowshield Plugin on our website - but i'm guessing that's not the issue. It's related to a redirect happening at the AWS level?
Is there a way to STOP that redirect?
Or force HTTPS on files that are downloaded from the bucket?
We don't have AWS CloudFront set up - Not clear on whether we HAVE to - as the files themselves on S3 show as https? (And I'm not sure how that set up might impact the S3 Flowshield delivery?)
Thanks in advance for any explanation/solution as I'm still learning.
Cheers
CBurgo

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce SSL by adding the following statement to your bucket policy.

```
{
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "s3:*",
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>",
        "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
            "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jellycsc, I'll give that a try....much appreciated mate! :)

Comment: Ummm, nope, didn't work. I get the following error.

Unknown Error
An unexpected error occurred.
API response
Missing required field Statement

Comment: Here's what I posted

{
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "s3:*",
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<greatmanagersacademy>",
        "arn:aws:s3:::<greatmanagersacademy>/*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
            "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
        }
    }
}

Comment: The code snippet above is not a complete bucket policy. It's just one of the statement objects. Please refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-policy-language-overview.html) page to add additional fields to make it a valid policy.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm working through that...... I've added the principal, I think....

Can't find anything related to ACTION and https

The bucket name is just greatmanagersacademy

Can you suggest what I'd need to enter for Action?

Comment: Nope, I can't get that to work........

I keep getting a Missing Field Statement or JSON error

Anyone?

Comment: Try this. Remember to replace <bucket-name> with your actual bucket name. {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Comment: THIS doesn't work......it's accepted as a policy but breaks the connection to the S3 Bucket via the S3 Flowshield Plugin.

{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::tests3https",
                "arn:aws:s3:::tests3https/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}